# ASP.NET Cast ListBox item to Custom Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a ListBox that i've bound items to, but when I try and retrieved the object from the ListBox at a later point I get a compiler error... Does anyone know what the deal is?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Project> projects;

    DeleteListBox.ItemType = "Project";
    DeleteListBox.DataValueField = "projName";

    using(DBMethods db = new DBMethods())
    {
        //Projects is not null during testing
        projects = db.getProjects() as List<Project>;
        DeleteListBox.DataSource = projects;
        DeleteListBox.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Now later I'm trying to retrieve the object from the ListBox but I get a red squiggly line under the entire line of code:

```
protected void PermDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(DBMethods db = new DBMethods())
    {
        //Compiler error here
        var toDelete = DeleteListBox.SelectedItem as Project;
    }
}
```

How can I cast my selected list item into a Project object without a compiler error? Cannot convert type 'SystemW.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'Project' via a reference conversion...

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a ListBox item back to a custom class, a `ListItem` is basically a Key Value Pair with two strings.

You have to store an indentifier in the ListBox that matches with a property in the `Project` class (in this example property `ID`).

```
DeleteListBox.DataSource = projects;
DeleteListBox.DataTextField = "Name";
DeleteListBox.DataValueField = "ID";
DeleteListBox.DataBind();
```

Then when the button is clicked, loop all the ListItems in the ListBox, check which ones are selected and find the correct `Project` in the list of Projects with `Linq`.

```
protected void PermDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in DeleteListBox.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            var toDelete = projects.Where(x => x.ID == Convert.ToInt32(item.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```